# Taghelpers with Bootstrap 4

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm trying to integrate Bootstrap 4 into my application. In my _Layout.cshtml file I have the following:

```
<link asp-href-include="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" asp-href-exclude="**/*-reboot*,**/*-grid*" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My bower configuration file:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~4.0.0"
  }
}
```

My _ViewImports.cshtml (in the /Views folder, not /Views/Shared folder) has

```
@addTaghelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Taghelpers
```

and I have `_Layout.cshtml` in my `_ViewStart.cshtml` file.

The bootstrap link doesn't seem to work when using the `asp-href-include` and `asp-href-exclude` taghelpers. The bootstrap layouts are not applied. When I use the basic

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in my `_Layout.cshtml`, Bootstrap is applied but not in the layout I want. How can I integrate the taghelpers to get the desired design?

Comment: can you please show your wwwroot/lib tree view of folders ?

Comment: @Ahmar wwwroot>>lib>>bootstrap>>dist>>css>>bootstrap.css>>bootstrap.min.css I've also just dragged/dropped the .css file and adjusted the taghelpers to ensure that it's pointing to the right file, but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid mistake, capitalizing the "H" in TagHelpers fixed it

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```